# appending to the list in dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have dataframe in following way:

```
vals = [[100,200], [100,200],[100,200]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':vals})
df['x'] = [1,2,3]

df
```

how can I append y values to the lists in x column, so my final values are in the following shape?

[image]

thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 1):

this would work

```py
import pandas as pd

vals = [[100,200], [100,200],[100,200]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':vals})
df['x'] = [1,2,3]

df["last"] = [ y + [x] for x, y in zip(df["x"], df["y"]) ] 

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["last"] = df.apply(lambda v: [*v.y, v.x], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            y  x           last
0  [100, 200]  1  [100, 200, 1]
1  [100, 200]  2  [100, 200, 2]
2  [100, 200]  3  [100, 200, 3]
```

---

Or:

```
df["last"] = df.y + df.x.apply(lambda x: [x])
```